# seff job efficiency report for all jobs in an array

Tags: slurm

I'm looking to gather the efficiency report for the all jobs in a job array. There's not really options for the seff command. When I run the seff command for an array job id, I only get the efficiency report for one job within the array.

Does anyone have an ideas on how I can get the efficiency report for all the jobs within the array or to gather cumulative statistics like mean, min and max for memory and CPU for all the jobs in a job array?

See my output below:

```
[user@cluster]$ seff 26838
Job ID: 26838
Array Job ID: 26835_1
Cluster: cluster
User/Group: user/HPCusers
State: COMPLETED (exit code 0)
Cores: 1
CPU Utilized: 00:05:29
CPU Efficiency: 103.13% of 00:05:19 core-walltime
Job Wall-clock time: 00:05:19
Memory Utilized: 125.11 MB
Memory Efficiency: 8.94% of 1.37 GB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment in the code for `seff` is "roughly equivalent":

```
sacct -P -n -a --format JobID,User,Group,State,Cluster,AllocCPUS,REQMEM,TotalCPU,Elapsed,MaxRSS,ExitCode,NNodes,NTasks -j <job_id>
```

But, unlike `seff`, it outputs info for each step in a job. I'm hoping it also outputs info for each job in a job array...

Comment: How/where can I install `seff` ?

Comment: @alper `seff` is part of the SLURM installation.

Comment: I have build from the source code but it did not come along

Comment: @alper What source code repo are you working from? It would be under the contribs directory.

Comment: I did : `git clone https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm ` and than `git checkout e2e21cb571ce88a6dd52989ec6fe30da8c4ef15f`  into `slurm-19-05-8-1`.  Isn't it correct  way to do it, I have also tried building on its master repo. Where can I find its `contribs directory`?